# Problemas de tradução no perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, perfil

Notei alguns pequenos problemas de tradução no meu perfil:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugiro as seguintes alternativas:

```
membro de  -> membro há
visitados  -> visitas
vistos     -> visto
```

Comment: Talvez para vistos seja melhor avistado

Comment: @TomásBadan Se diz assim em Portugal? No Brasil é mais comum "visto" mesmo (como em "fulano foi visto pela última vez ontem").

Comment: Em portugal eu não sei e nem mesmo sou tradutor, mas acredito que as duas se encaixem, embora eu prefira a segunda forma, ou seja, avistado

Comment: @TomásBadan vc é brasileiro?

Comment: @Math Sim, sou brasileiro, pq?

Comment: @TomásBadan pq geralmente existem inumeras formas de se dizer uma coisa, e uma forma as vezes é mais popular em um pais e outra forma é mais popular em outro país, apenas queria saber se era esse o caso. A proposito prefiro `visto` do que `avistado`, apenas minha opinião

Comment: Em pt_PT ambos `visto` e `avistado` funcionam. Em pt_PT eu diria `"membro desde à"` mas talvez essa forma com `"à"` não exista em pt_BR?

Comment: "Member for" é o mais difícil de traduzir. Por exemplo, "Membro desde" funciona com "hoje", mas não com "x dias/meses"; "Membro há" funciona com "x dias/meses", mas não com "hoje". "Desde há" não é redundante? @Sergio

Comment: @bfavaretto redundante não é mas a haver só uma frase para singular e plurar a sua sugestão de correcção é a melhor. Se houver possibilidade, então em pt_PT faria mais sentido "membro desde à" para o caso plural. Diz-se assim em pt_BR? Se a forma em pt_BR fôr "desde há" então a sua versão é mesmo a melhor até para o caso plural

Comment: Pensando melhor, não é mesmo redundante. Dizemos sim "desde há um mês", mas soa bem formal. Tem certeza que em pt_PT é "desde à" e não "desde há"? Acho que é sempre "desde há". Não sei qual é a melhor solução para o problema do hoje versus qualquer outra coisa. @Sergio

Comment: pt_PT 
membro desde ou membro há ||
visitas ||  
visto desde ou visto há

Comment: @Sklivvz could you implement bfavaretto's suggestion please. This has been reported since day #1 and nothing done.

Comment: @Sergio actually it's up to Gabe to decide

Comment: @Sklivvz, thank you for a light speed answer! This is wrong in all Portuguese versions out there in the world. Gabe had 151 days since this was posted and he didn't fix it. So I cry for help to you guys. I cannot even call Gabe now, his profile says "last seen 2 days ago".

Comment: @Sergio He's not working on weekends. I'm crazy enough to be always around :-D

Comment: @Sklivvz Maybe because you are getting fun instead of working. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

Quanto a vistos → visto, concordo. Aliás, foi minha [pergunta duplicada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325/traducao-de-seen-no-perfil-do-usuario) (ops!).

Quanto a visitados → visitas, concordo. Parece bem óbvio e eu nem havia percebido.

Quanto a membro, eu estava em dúvida sobre as melhores opções e havia decidido esperar e pensar um pouco a respeito.

Analisemos as formas com preposição (desde, por, de) e as com verbo (faz, há), bem como desde há:

- Agora: funciona apenas com desde.
- Hoje: funciona apenas com desde.
- Cinco anos atrás: funciona apenas com desde.
- Cinco anos: funciona com por, de, faz, há, desde há. Destas, membro de é a que soa menos usual, mas acho que faz sentido: criança de cinco anos, membro de cinco anos.

Parece-me que desde funciona com tempo pontual, enquanto por, de e faz funcionam com duração de tempo. Há e desde há funcionam com tempo pontual, mas o uso de atrás é considerado pleonasmo bárbaro.

A solução ideal é que haja concordância do rótulo com o dado. Se isso não for possível, acho que podemos ignorar agora e hoje já que são raros, restando escolher dentre por, de, faz, há e desde há.

Comment: Acho que "desde há" é o mais correto, o mais percetível.