# Tradução de seen no perfil do usuário

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

No perfil do usuário, *seen* foi traduzido para vistos.

[image: Excerto do perfil do usuário]

Entretanto, *seen* refere-se ao usuário, então deveria ser apenas visto: *(this user was) seen 15 minutes ago* → (este usuário foi) visto 15 minutos atrás.

Não sei como funciona a tradução do Stack Exchange, mas há que se lembrar de que *seen* pode também ser traduzido para vistos em outros contextos quando empregado como adjetivo qualificando um plural.